# Как уменьшить таймаут SSL_accept?

Tags: linux, c

Ошибка такая. У меня приложение на ssl шифровании. Я решил попробовать и посмотреть что будет, если подключиться с помощью обычного nc. Результат не понравился. nc намертво вешает SSL_accept и все. Пробовал уменьшить таймаут ssl, но не помогло.

```
SSL_SESSION *session = SSL_SESSION_new ();
SSL_set_timeout (session, 2);
init_ssl (dc, client);
SSL_set_session (dc->ssl, session);
ret = SSL_accept (dc->ssl);
```

Comment: не висит, а ждет hello

Comment: @eri что в этом случае пишут программисты? Как решить проблему?

Comment: Отправьте через `nc` что-нибудь длиной от 4-х байт. 100% это не совпадёт с бинарным форматом SSL и сервер отвалится. Пример: `echo hello | nc google.com 443` - сервер закрывает соединение мгновенно.

Comment: Для тестирования SSL лучше пользоваться `s_client` - это приложение отрабатывает SSL handshake и создаёт защищённое соединение.

Comment: @switch, по идее надо нижележащий сокет перевести в неблокирующий режим, тогда, если в нём нет данных `SSL_accept()` вернёт ошибку, а затем надо дождаться готовности чтения/записи обычными `poll()`/`select()` (с таймаутом по вкусу)... `SSL_set_timeout()` же по идее устанавливает таймаут самой сессии...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ваш пример не очень помог, он не сработал у меня. но я начал применять select. и сокет оставил блокирующим. и вот в чем проблема. когда select возвращает available data, значит я подключился с помощью nc (netcat). если я успеваю при подключении nc ввести один символ, то он зависает на этапа SSL_accept. но если ввиду больше 3 символов, то SSL_accept вернет ошибку и все нормально заработает. о, я придумал. а можно как то узнать размер буфера, который пришел, до SSL_accept, но если буфер пришел  в нормальном количестве (более 3 символов), то чтобы SSL_accept его использовал?

Comment: вроде recv и MSG_PEEK поможет

Comment: @switcher, плохая идея... `SSL_accept()` выполняет SSL-рукопожатие полностью т.е. он несколько раз независимо читает и пишет в сокет... даже если ты дождёшься полноценного `ClientHello` и проверишь, что он корректный, то ты ни как не сможешь проверить, что клиент будет молчать в ответ на дальнейшие шаги... что с неблокирующим сокетом не получилось? (желательно в виде [mcve] в вопрос или на какой-нить pastebin)... по идее это предполагаемый вариант реализации...